# Should I use the preposition before the infinitive verb form?

Tags: verbs, translation, prepositions

I am a bit confused about using the infinitive of verbs.

For example:

> He used a map to find the village.

Should I translate this as

> Ha usato una mappa trovare il villaggio.

OR

> Ha usato una mappa a trovare il villaggio.

I have seen examples of both and I don't know which is correct.

Comment: And, in addition to my nit-picking below about “village” vs. “villaggio”, note that “map” too has not an exact equivalent in “mappa”. [“Mappa”](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/mappa/), properly, only should be used for a limited range of cartographic representations (those at a scale larger than 1/1000: essentially, only maps of the Catasto [land registry]); otherwise, one should use *carta (geografica)* or *pianta (di una città etc.)*

Comment: Thank you, DaG, for your contributions to my Italian language learning curve. Usually my somewhat unlearned examples are not the actual sentence I am trying to translate but merely an example. All contributions, however, are appreciated.

Comment: Thanks, @Jim's Mum. Of course I didn't intend to criticise you: I only seized the opportunity to mention an inaccuracy common to many Italians as well (and to myself as well, until someone pointed out this to me!).

Comment: Keep the suggestions coming, @DaG. Your English is way better than my baby Italian. I have written another entry for my blog http://mioitalia.com/ so any help to improve is welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> "Ha usato una mappa"

is the main/independent clause;

> "*per* trovare il paese"

is a subordinate/dependent implicit final clause.

The implicit final clause usually requires

> *per* + *infinitive mood of the verb*

If the main clause has a verb expressing movement, you can use

> *a* + *infinitive mood of the verb*

For example:

> "Si è messo *a cercare* il paese sulla mappa"

In some cases you can also use "allo scopo di", "al fine di", "onde", etc. (these are more formal, more common in writing).

Note that the subject of an implicit final clause is the same subject of the main clause; if this is not the case you need to use an explicit final clause (*affinché, perché, etc.*). Example: "Lui tirò fuori la mappa *affinché/perché* lei cercasse il paese".

Also note that in this answer I am assuming that the question is about final clauses - although there are obviously many other cases where you use the infinitive of a verb, and it would be too long to describe each case here.

Comment: Thank you randomatlabuser for your informative response. This has been bugging me for ages and this helps to make it much clearer.

Comment: Moreover, @Jim's Mum, as implicitly randomatlabuser reminds us in his examples, note that an Italian *villaggio* isn't exactly the same as an English “village”. The latter is often better translated as *paese*, *paesino*, *cittadina*, while a *villaggio* tends to refer to a rather primitive settlement (*un villaggio di capanne*) or a picturesque one (*un villaggio di pescatori*), apart from some specialised use (*villaggio vacanze* etc.).

Answer (score 0):

Si tratta di una frase composta da una proposizione principale

> Ha usato una mappa

e di una subordinata in forma implicita di tipo finale (specifica quindi un fine o scopo legato al verbo usare) che si rende con la proposizione "per" seguita dal verbo all'infinito (forma implicita, infatti)
La seconda forma

> Ha usato una mappa a trovare il villaggio

ritengo sia errata.