# Uses of the Infinitive

Tags: infinitive

I am trying to understand how to create sentences using the infinitive after prepositions per, prima di, and senza.  I am searching for examples to help me study and not coming up with anything other than what is in my textbook - any suggestions or comments on how it is best to construct these sentences?

Comment: Related: http://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/2261/should-i-use-the-preposition-before-the-infinitive-verb-form

Comment: Welcome to Italian.SE!

Answer (score 5):

Usage examples with *per*:

- corro per arrivare prima  (I run to arrive earlier)
- mi avvicino per sentire meglio (I move closer to hear better)
- faccio ginnastica per dimagrire. (I exercise to lose weight)

Examples with *prima di*:

- controllo i bagagli prima di partire ( I check my luggage before leaving)
- spegni le luci prima di andare a letto (switch off the light before going to sleep)
- mi lavo sempre le mani prima di mangiare (I always wash my hands before eating)

Examples with *senza*:

- mio fratello è uscito senza salutare (my brother left without saying goodbye)
- sono rimasto in piedi senza parlare per un'ora (I stood without saying a word for an hour)
- non si può stare senza mangiare per giorni (you can't go without food for days)

Hope it helps.